# Flask: render a page after jQuery ajax $.post call

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I send data from a form with jQuery $.post() to a flask function. The function does some long running calculation the data. In this case, I don't want to send back some HTML but rather render a new template. How can I do this when I call the function with jQuery/AJAX?

The form:

```
<form id='myform'>
    <input type='text'> some input...
    <input type='button' value='send form' id='mybutton'>
</form>
```

Calculation on form input takes some time, so I send it with jQuery:

```
$.("#mybutton").click(function() {
    // get the data in form
    $exampledata = 'foo'
    $.post("/some/flask/function", {'data': $exampledata}, function(response) {
      can I render a new template here with data from flask function?
    });
});
```

In flask, the corresponding function looks like this:

```
@app.route('/some/flask/function', methods=['POST'])
def longCalculation():        
    form = request.form
    data = form['data']

    result = runTheLongCalculation(data)
    this does not work -->
    return render_template('result.html',r=result)
    how can I render a new template after an jQuery/AJAX call?
```

I don't want to send back a redirect URL and JSON, but actually render a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the template you render is simply a piece of HTML, you can return it like you have shown in your Flask code and do the following in the browser:

```
$.("#mybutton").click(function() {
    // get the data in form
    $exampledata = 'foo'
    $.post("/some/flask/function", {'data': $exampledata}, function(response) {
        var myDiv = $('#resultarea'); // The place where you want to inser the template
        myDiv.html(response);
    });
});
```

This expects your Flask template to look something like this:

```
<div id='result'>
    {{ result }}
</div>
```

It can be bigger, but we are inserting it inside the page so no sidebars, menu navigation or html/body tags, just a simple piece of HTML.

The problem arises if you send back a fully fledged HTML page with your Flask function, as it will not be rendered correctly inside the existing page.

Comment: That would work. Problem is: The 'result' is big and complex. It's easy to put it in a table with a template. But it wouldn't be nice to compile long HTML output in the Python/flask function ...

Comment: More general: Do you have an idea about the best way to save (lots of) data generated after an AJAX request and access it from the next request (i.e. a simple window.location.replace() in the $.post callback).

Comment: More generally, you could have it calculate/generate the data, save it locally (server-side, to some temporary store like memcached or redis or even to disk) and redirect to another page with a specific parameter (an ID or similar for the calculation) that then shows the result as a normal webpage.

However, there's nothing wrong with sending a lot of data through an AJAX call - for all intents and purposes it works just the same as a "normal" HTTP request.

Comment: I thought about redis, and I think I'll go for it. Depending on traffic the calculation can actually take some time ... so it's anyway safer to store server-side and access this again.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out a lot of ways to do this:

I think the best method to send data from a long running server-side calculation to a new page is to use some kind of server-side storage. This way everything works even if the browser is closed or the user leaves the website.

I go for redis because it's dead simple and fast.